# Windows Form TextBox User input

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm new to windows forms and have never tried it before, i mainly do razorpages and stuff along those lines.

I'm making a form that is suppose to create an account. i have a Class account with a bunch of properties already, the problem is that i can't seem to figure out how i make whatever is written in the textboxes = my Account properties.

I've tried making properties in the form and initializing them to my account properties liek this Firstname = Account.FirstName; but i just get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when i run it.

```
public partial class AddAccountDialog : Form
{
#region Properties

        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; 
            set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        private bool Accepted { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
        public AddAccountDialog()
        {
            #region Applying Properties
    
            Id = Account.UserID;
            Firstname = Account.FirstName;
            Lastname = Account.LastName;
            Username = Account.Username;
    
            Accepted = false;
    
    
            #endregion
    
            #region Setup Methods
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupForm();
            ShowDialog();
            #endregion
        }
    
        private void SetupForm()
        {
            
    
        }
    
        private void textBox_user_id_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Id = textBox_user_id.Text;
        }
    
        private void textBox_firstname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Firstname = textBox_firstname.Text;
        }
    
        private void textBox_lastname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lastname = textBox_lastname.Text;
        }
    
        private void textBox_username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Username = textBox_username.Text;
        }
    
        private void textBox_password_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Password = textBox_password.Text;
        }
    
        private void button_accept_changes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Accepted = true;
    
            if (textBox_firstname.Text == "" || 
                    textBox_lastname.Text == "" || 
                        textBox_username.Text == "" || 
                            textBox_password.Text == "") { MessageBox.Show("Udfyld alle kasser"); }
            else
            {
                //Account.FirstName = textBox_firstname.Text;
                //Account.LastName = textBox_lastname.Text;
                //Account.Username = textBox_username.Text;
                //Account.UserID = textBox_user_id.Text;
    
                Account = new Account();
    
                Account.ToString();
                //Close();
            }
    
        }
        public Account GetResponse()
        {
            Close();
    
            if (Accepted) return Account;
            else return null;
    
            Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Account class

```
 public class Account
    {

        #region Properties

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; } }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string[] AllowedPermissionIDS { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        #endregion
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>

        public Account(string firstName, string lastName, string username, string userId, string[] allowedPermissionIds, bool isAdmin)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Username = username;
            UserID = userId;
            AllowedPermissionIDS = allowedPermissionIds;
            IsAdmin = isAdmin;
        }
        public Account()
        {
            
        }
```

Comment: Instead of `Id = Account.UserID` it should probably be `textBox_user_id.Text = Account.UserID`. There are probably several errors in the code, but the one you wrote about (null reference exception) is not visible from the shown code. How do you use this class?

Comment: i tried that too, but i still get the null reference exception. 

how do i use my Account class or what class do you mean?

Comment: You have the line of code … `public Account Account { get; set; }` … Where is the `Account` Class defined? What properties does it have? Can you show this `Account` Class? It is odd that the code defines this `Account` variable, then later in the  `button_accept_changes_Click` event the code creates a new `Account` object with… `Account = new Account();` … ? … but how are that `Account`’s “properties” getting set? It appears you may be defining variables… “Id, Firstname”... etc. unnecessarily. I am guessing you want to use `Account.ID` and `Account.FirstName` etc… Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: @JohnG I added the account class. Yea its kind of a mess since im new to forms, its very different from what im used to, but i dont need all the properties since the id is getting auto generated and the password im not sure what they will do with that. i just need Firstname, Lastname, Username, and password to be equal the respective textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this in the `button_accept_changes_Click` event? It is unclear why the code is commented out, but it should go something like…

```
Account = new Account();

Account.FirstName = textBox_firstname.Text;
Account.LastName = textBox_lastname.Text;
Account.Username = textBox_username.Text;
Account.UserID = textBox_user_id.Text;
```

Comment: ahh so that is the way to do it. i commented it out because it didn't work so i wanted to try something else. so rather than deleting i just comment it out

Comment: You need to keep in mind that when you call the `Account`s blank constructor like… `Account = new Account()` … then the “properties” `FirstName`, `LastName` etc.… will be `null` as they have not yet been initialized… so if you try to use them you may get the `null` exception.